# ASP page scraping in wpf

Tags: wpf, web

I want to scrap the content of an asp-based web pages from WPF application, and I want to know what is the best way
is it using WebBrowser control? or is there a lighter way to do that?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly shouldn't need to use a WebBrowser control. All you need to use is a [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to pull down the page's HTML as a string. You can then parse that using a regular expression or something. Have a look at the example at the bottom of the WebClient MSDN page.